# How can i recover a vdi file that was affected by dd?

Tags: virtualbox, data-recovery

Detail: i accidentally used dd of=myfile.vdi and it went to 0 byte after.

is there a way to recover the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: You can try what is in the answers, but with `dd` it is actually known to overwrite the entire file and not just delete the file pointer like a normal delete will do.  `dd` is also known as disk/data duplicator or disk destroyer because of the way that it handles data.  So your `.vdi` file may not be recoverable.

Comment: its a very important vm, can you help me how i could have it recovered

Comment: If it's very important, then you of course have a backup....